# Subclassing win32com objects

Tags: python, ms-office, win32com

I ran win32com makepy.main() on the Microsoft PowerPoint object library and it generated this [file](https://gist.github.com/Melendowski/82b83986086cb05f2621369e144180ee). Viewing the classes it generated, along with those found in the vba documentation. It appears it created classes for every single object within the PowerPoint object library.

My question is, would I be able to subclass these classes? If I can, how do I do it? I'm lost on how this would work. I subclass a Slide object, how do I tell PowerPoint return my subclasses slide object? After running the makepy, It generated a gen_py folder where this file can be found.

Comment: Think this is a Python question?

Comment: It is a python question, but I tagged VBA because its somewhat related to it.

Comment: I'm not even sure what yo are asking (having no Python experience), but you probably should include a Python tag to find you audience.

Comment: Ok I changed the tag.

Comment: I *think* what you asking is if you can make the PowerPoint API return some custom object? (In that case no, it is an API, a contract, it returns what it returns.)

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. Essentially I need to "delegate" to these objects rather than trying to subclass them.

Comment: Since I do not know Python, nor what exactly it is that you are trying to accomplish, I cannot answer that. It would help if you gave us an example of your intentions, including the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using early binding with `win32com`. Whenever you use early binding it auto-generates python files that can then be used to help with code completion and things of that nature.

Now, you mention an interesting question of how can we `subclass` these auto-generated files. That problem is that this can become complicated because in some cases you can only get an object if the parent object exists. What I found is I must auto-generate all the COM objects that exist in the object model. That way if I call a method that returns another object, I won't get this mix between early and late-bound objects.

I guess at the end of the day what exactly you are trying to do once you `subclass` this object.